# Equivalent to sns.distplot(data, fit=scipy.stats.norm) with plotly

Tags: python, plotly, seaborn, plotly-python, plotly-express

For a while, I've been using both `seaborn` and `plotly` for visualization, depending on my needs at the moment. Lately, I've been trying to move completely to `plotly`, but there are things that I still can't find out how to make it work.

For example, I used to use seaborn to check the distribution of some data, to see how well it fitted to the gaussian distribution. This can be easily done with the following snippet:

```
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import norm

sns.distplot(data, fit=norm)
```

I've been trying to achieve some similar quick gaussian check with `plotly express` (`px.histogram` to be more specific), but I can't get it done. Could you please help me with this matter?

EDIT

An example for "data" would be:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)

data = np.random.noncentral_chisquare(3, 20, 1000)
```

The output should show data histogram with its KDE, plus a gaussian equivalent KDE. This is helpful when testing transformations results (log, box-cox...)

Comment: Do you mind to add the data you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can be interested in reading [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/best-plotly-equivalent-to-sns-distplot-data-fit-norm/34919/3). Apparently at the moment the easiest way it's using `plotly.figure_factory.create_dist_plot` but from the link above it looks like it's going to be discontinued.

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

np.random.seed(123)
data = np.random.noncentral_chisquare(3, 20, 1000)

m = data.mean()
s = data.std()
gaussian_data = np.random.normal(m, s, 10000)

fig = ff.create_distplot(
    [data, gaussian_data],
    group_labels=["plot", "gaussian"],
    curve_type="kde")

fig.data = [fig.data[0], fig.data[2], fig.data[3]]

fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

And if instead of `fig.data = ...` you use

```py
lst = list(fig.data)
lst.pop(1)
fig.data = tuple(lst)
```

you'll get
[image]

Comment: Yep, that was me asking in plotly forum. The problems with that solution are that ff.create_distplot is going to be discontinued, as you say, and that you have to create a big sample to ensure the gaussian data is truly gaussian (bigger than the original data). Would you be able to manage to adress those two issues? Maybe with px.histogram, and adding another trace...